# Is there a way to optimize the query given below

Tags: sql-server

I have the following Query and i need the query to fetch data from SomeTable based on the filter criteria present in the Someothertable. If there is nothing present in SomeOtherTable  Query should return me all the data present in SomeTable

SQL SERVER 2005

SomeOtherTable does not have any indexes or any constraint all fields are char(50)

The Following Query work fine for my requirements but it causes performance problems when i have lots of parameters.

Due to some requirement of Client, We have to keep all the Where clause data in SomeOtherTable.  depending on subid data will be joined with one of the columns in SomeTable.

For example the Query can can be

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SomeTable
WHERE
    1=1 
AND
(
SomeTable.ID in (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM SomeOtherTable  WHERE Name = 'ABC' and subid = 'EF')
OR
0=(SELECT Count(1) FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE spName = 'ABC' and subid = 'EF')
)

AND 
    (
    SomeTable.date =(SELECT date FROM SomeOtherTable  WHERE Name = 'ABC' and subid = 'Date')
    OR
    0=(SELECT Count(1) FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE spName = 'ABC' and subid = 'Date')
    )
```

EDIT----------------------------------------------

I think i might have to explain my problem in detail:

We have developed an ASP.net application that is used to invoke parametrize crystal reports, parameters to the crystal reports are not passed using the default  crystal reports method.

In ASP.net application we have created wizards which are used to pass the parameters to the Reports, These parameters are not directly consumed by the crystal report but are consumed by the Query embedded inside the crystal report or the Stored procedure used in the Crystal report.

This is achieved using a table (SomeOtherTable) which holds parameter data as long as report is running after which the data is deleted, as such we can assume that SomeOtherTable  has max 2 to 3 rows at any given point of time.

So if we look at the above query initial part of the Query can be assumed as the Report Query and the where clause is used to get the user input from the SomeOtherTable table.

So i don't think it will be useful to create indexes etc  (May be i am wrong).

Comment: Can you post sample DDL of the SomeTable and SomeOtherTable tables (and indexes)? Without that, you will not get good answers on how to make this perform best.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? That will also influence the answers correctness.

Comment: just wondering, why was this downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to stick to my original Query.

Answer (score 3):

> SomeOtherTable does not have any
>   indexes or any constraint all fields
>   are char(50)

Well, there's your problem.  There's nothing you can do to a query like this which will improve its performance if you create it like this.

- You need a proper primary or other candidate key designated on all of your tables.  That is to say, you need at least ONE unique index on the table.  You can do this by designating one or more fields as the PK, or you can add a UNIQUE constraint or index.
- You need to define your fields properly.  Does the field store integers?  Well then, an INT field may just be a better bet than a CHAR(50).

You can't "optimize" a query that is based on an unsound schema.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    SomeTable
LEFT JOIN SomeOtherTable ON SomeTable.ID=SomeOtherTable.ID AND Name = 'ABC'
WHERE
    1=1 
AND
(
SomeOtherTable.ID IS NOT NULL
OR
0=(SELECT Count(1) FROM SomeOtherTable WHERE spName = 'ABC')
)
```

Comment: Well i changed my query according to your suggestions but it took double the time to return results.

Answer (score 1):

also put 'with (nolock)' after each table name to improve performance

Comment: that is the worst advice you can give. using NOLOCK just to "speed things up" is just silly. you have to know the side effects of it too.

Comment: I agree with @Mladen Prajdic; NOLOCK is to be used with caution, not carte blanche.

Comment: This is absolutely terrible advice.  NOLOCK should not be used in production systems anymore, and it should only have been used in previous versions very judiciously.  Read up about SNAPSHOT isolation adn READ COMMITTED with row versioning instead.

Answer (score 1):

The following might speed you up

```
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
WHERE
   SomeTable.ID in 
        (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM SomeOtherTable Where Name = 'ABC')
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM SomeTable 
Where 
   NOT EXISTS (Select spName From SomeOtherTable Where spName = 'ABC')
```

The UNION will effectivly split this into two simpler queries which can be optiomised separately (depends very much on DBMS, table size etc whether this will actually improve performance -- but its always worth a try).

The "EXISTS" key word is more efficient than the "SELECT COUNT(1)" as it will return true as soon as the first row is encountered.

Comment: A UNION ALL would be more faster than UNION as the result set are different and unique.

Comment: Union will not be feasible for me as my select queries can span across 100 lines and i may have 9 where clauses. In that case i might have to write entire thing nine times

Comment: If your select query is 100 lines, then you will have performance problems.

Answer (score 1):

Or check if the value exists in db first
And you can remove the distinct keyword in your query, it is useless here.

if EXISTS (Select spName From SomeOtherTable Where spName = 'ABC') 
begin
    SELECT * 
    FROM SomeTable 
    WHERE
   SomeTable.ID in 
        (SELECT ID FROM SomeOtherTable Where Name = 'ABC')
end 
else
begin
    SELECT * 
    FROM SomeTable 
end

Comment: Why would you need multiple where clauses? If you have multiple values to check for in the SomeOtherTable then use an INCLUDE/IN.

Comment: you need to build your sql string in 'multiple where' scenario. It is dynamic sql so you need to pay attention to security related.

Answer (score 0):

Aloha

Try

```
select t.* from SomeTable t
    left outer join SomeOtherTable o
        on t.id = o.id
where (not exists (select id from SomeOtherTable where spname = 'adbc')
OR spname = 'adbc')
```

-Edoode

Comment: Well i changed my query according to your suggestions but it took double the time to return results.

Comment: Well, you gave us no description of the table or the data involved, so you will get our best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

change all your select statements in the where part to inner jons.
the OR conditions should be union all-ed.
also make sure your indexing is ok.

sometimes it pays to have an intermediate table for temp results to which you can join to.

Comment: Please check the comments for the first post

Comment: then definitely use temp tables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that there is no need for the "1=1 AND" in your query.  1=1 will always evaluate to be true, leaving the software to evaluate the next part... why not just skip the 1=1 and evaluate the juicy part?